# Fitted surface does not resemble the heatmap produced from the same data

Tags: python, matplotlib, linear-regression, heatmap, surface

I have some z values spanning over a grid of, say, 8 x and 10 z values. The z values can be depicted as a heatmap over the x-y plane (left subplot). Now I want to fit a surface to the same data that are shown in the heatmap. However, the fitted surface (right subplot) does not at all look like the heatmap. What am I doing wrong here?
Also, if I remove the `.T` from the `contour1 = ...` line (as some have suggested), I get a type error because the shapes do not match.

Here's the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x_values = np.linspace(1, 8, 8)
y_values = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)
z_values = [[0.0128, 0.0029, 0.0009, 0.0006, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0049, 0.0157, 0.0067, 0.0003, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0203, 0.0096, 0.0055, 0.0096, 0.0012, 0.0023, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0229, 0.0191, 0.0020, 0.0073, 0.0055, 0.0026, 0.0022, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0218, 0.0357, 0.0035, 0.0133, 0.0073, 0.0145, 0.0000, 0.0029, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0261, 0.0232, 0.0365, 0.0200, 0.0212, 0.0107, 0.0036, 0.0007, 0.0022, 0.0007],
            [0.0305, 0.0244, 0.0284, 0.0786, 0.0226, 0.0160, 0.0000, 0.0196, 0.0007, 0.0007],
            [0.0171, 0.0189, 0.0598, 0.0215, 0.0218, 0.0464, 0.0399, 0.0051, 0.0000, 0.0000]]
z_values = np.array(z_values)

x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))

ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
contour1 = ax1.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, np.log(z_values.T + 1))
fig.colorbar(contour1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('x values')
ax1.set_ylabel('y values')

x_flat = x_grid.flatten()
y_flat = y_grid.flatten()
z_flat = z_values.flatten()

degree = 4
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(np.column_stack((x_flat, y_flat)))

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly, z_flat)

z_pred = model.predict(X_poly)
z_pred_grid = z_pred.reshape(x_grid.shape)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(x_grid, y_grid, np.log(z_pred_grid + 1), cmap='viridis')
ax2.set_xlabel('x values')
ax2.set_ylabel('y values')
ax2.set_zlabel('z values')

plt.show()
```

And here's the figure:

[image]

Comment: You're not using your `z_flat` in the fit.

Comment: But what about `model.fit(X_poly, z_flat)`?

Comment: Apologies, my IDE didn't highlight the variable correctly. In that case, your polynomial degree might be too low for the level of features you want to see. Try increasing it.

Comment: Your flattening and subsequent fitting appears to have transposed x and y.

Comment: Oh gosh - it's actually that simple?! I think that's it...! Thank you

Comment: @lastchance: But how can I actually correct this if `x_value` and `y_value`do not have the same length? In this case, having `z_pred_grid.T` produces a shape mismatch.

Comment: Sorry, @PingPong, I can't manage to get sklearn to install on my python platform in order to sort it out. I can only suggest that you look very carefully at the ordering of 2-d data in the lines involving ```np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values)```, ```.flatten()``` and ```.fit_transform(np.column_stack((x_flat, y_flat)))```. My observation is that the heatmap shows peaks at high x/low y whilst the polyfit shows peaks at high-y, low x. It might even be down to the ordering of your z-values, where the peaks are high-row/low-column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED FOLLOWING COMMENTS**

If you use the default numpy.meshgrid call then the layout of your x and y values with respect to the dependent-variable array corresponds to the following: (print `x_grid`, `y_grid` and `z_values` out if you want to see):

```
    x ------->
 y
 |   [dependent-]
 |   [variable  ]
\|/  [ array    ]
```

Your poly-fitted figure corresponds to this, but your heat-map doesn't. I think that's because you **transposed z** in the heatmap plot but you **didn't transpose z** in the polyfit.

Whatever you do, you need to use the **SAME dependent-variable array** in both figures.

You have TWO choices: either (1) transpose the dependent-variable array before any plotting and leave the meshgrid call as it is; or (2) leave the dependent-variable array as it is but change the indexing order in meshgrid.

Full code below. Please note the 2 options (given by easily-changed variable `option`).

The output figure is the same in both cases. The peaks of the diagrams now correspond between the two subfigures. They are at high-x/low-y.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import PolynomialFeatures
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

x_values = np.linspace(1, 8, 8)  
y_values = np.linspace(1, 10, 10)

z_values = [[0.0128, 0.0029, 0.0009, 0.0006, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0049, 0.0157, 0.0067, 0.0003, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0203, 0.0096, 0.0055, 0.0096, 0.0012, 0.0023, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0229, 0.0191, 0.0020, 0.0073, 0.0055, 0.0026, 0.0022, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0218, 0.0357, 0.0035, 0.0133, 0.0073, 0.0145, 0.0000, 0.0029, 0.0000, 0.0000],
            [0.0261, 0.0232, 0.0365, 0.0200, 0.0212, 0.0107, 0.0036, 0.0007, 0.0022, 0.0007],
            [0.0305, 0.0244, 0.0284, 0.0786, 0.0226, 0.0160, 0.0000, 0.0196, 0.0007, 0.0007],
            [0.0171, 0.0189, 0.0598, 0.0215, 0.0218, 0.0464, 0.0399, 0.0051, 0.0000, 0.0000]]

#### If you want x to vary with ROW rather than the default COLUMN then choose ONE of these two approaches
option = 2
if ( option == 1 ):        # Default meshgrid, but transpose the dependent variables
   z_values = np.array(z_values).T
   x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values)
else:                      # Leave the dependent variable, but use non-default meshgrid arrangement: indexing='ij'
   z_values = np.array(z_values)
   x_grid, y_grid = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values,indexing='ij')


fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12, 5))
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(121)
contour1 = ax1.contourf(x_grid, y_grid, np.log(z_values + 1))
fig.colorbar(contour1, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('x values')
ax1.set_ylabel('y values')

x_flat = x_grid.flatten()
y_flat = y_grid.flatten()
z_flat = z_values.flatten()

degree = 4
poly_features = PolynomialFeatures(degree=degree)
X_poly = poly_features.fit_transform(np.column_stack((x_flat, y_flat)))

model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X_poly, z_flat)

z_pred = model.predict(X_poly)
z_pred_grid = z_pred.reshape(x_grid.shape)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(122, projection='3d')
ax2.plot_surface(x_grid, y_grid, np.log(z_pred_grid + 1), cmap='viridis')
ax2.set_xlabel('x values')
ax2.set_ylabel('y values')
ax2.set_zlabel('z values')

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks @lastchance. But the things is: removing the `.T` works in this example where `x_values` and ỳ_values` have the same lenght. If they don't, removing `.T` produces a type error because the shapes do not match.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are saying, @Pingpong. The dimensions simply have to match those in the z_values array. If I reduce the x size to 8, say, and simultaneously remove the last 2 columns of the z_values array, then everything is fine (as long as you don't transpose the z_values array).

Comment: Basically, DON'T transpose z_values in the heat map and make sure that x has the same dimension as the COLUMNS of z_values, whilst y has the same dimension as the ROWS of z_values.

Comment: I have edited the original question, now with 8 `x_values` and 10 `y_values`. If I don't transpose the `z_values`, I get a type error. Moreover, as you can see from the `z_values` data, they peak at high-x and low-y (rows are x, columns are y), Therefore, both of your figures are "wrong" because they peak at low-x, high-y.

Comment: I want the rows of `z_values` to represent x and the columns to represent y.

Comment: @PingPong, please see my revised post. You have a choice of EITHER transposing the z_values array before doing any plotting, OR changing the indexing order in the meshgrid command. Whichever you use, the same dependent-variable array must go to both plotting routines, not transposed in one and untransposed in the other.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257275/discussion-between-pingpong-and-lastchance).